# Custom sorting DataGrid without ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I would like to do custom sorting for my `ItemsSource` as I get this exception:

> Failed to compare two elements in the array.

This is obvious as I use a converter class to display the proper value based on the object. The object is of type `object` and can contain multiple types, so the sorting doesn't work here. I went on the internet but the only solution is for a `ListCollectionView`, which mine isn't. This wouldn't be such a bad thing, except for the fact that the other `CollectionView` class doesn't provide us with a `CustomSort` property.

One way I could thing of solving this is by using the `SortMemberPath` property on the `DataGridTextColumn`, but this is far from ideal as I need to create a new property for each property I display (with the use of the converter). This results in unneeded clutter and makes my classes look terrible. This 'solution' also seems like a bit of a complete workaround to me and I hope that there is a better solution. The only problem is, I couldn't find it, does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no easy way of sorting by using the CollectionView or OOTB features of the DataGrid. One Solution could be to sort your list which you bound as the ItemsSource.